# passar o valor de uma variável python para uma busca no mysql

Tags: mysql, python, busca-binária

estou com uma demanda e ainda não consegui solucionar. É o seguinte:

```
def main():

    chave = [valores_lidos]
    while(chave!=-1):

        vetor = valores_lidos
        chave= int(input("Informe o numero de id da vaca para buscar a ultima ordenha: "))
        posicao = busca_binaria(vetor, 0, len(vetor) - 1, chave)
        if posicao <=0 :
            print("a vaca %d nao foi encontrado." % chave)
            break
        else:
               print(f"A vaca de nº %d foi encontrada e sua ultima ordenha foi em {data}" % chave)

        print("Busca concluida! ")
        break
main()
```

No `script` acima, a variável `CHAVE` recebe um número e preciso usar este número inserido nesta variável para fazer a busca no mysql. Segue abaixo o script de busca no mysql. Sei que estou fazendo errado, mas, não sei como é a maneira certa. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda aqui. Trata-se de um trabalho acadêmico e meu prazo está no fim.

```
import mysql.connector

from mysql import connector

conexao = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'root',
                                  host='localhost',
                                  database = 'fazenda_bd')

comando_sql2 = 'select data_ordenha from leite where id = chave'
curs.execute(comando_sql2)
valores_lidos2 = curs.fetchall()
lista = (valores_lidos2)
nova =str(' '.join([str(_) for _ in lista]))
data = nova[1:30].replace(', ', '/')
print(data)
```

A primeiro linha após a importação que se trata da busca no mysql.

OBS:

Não postei o código inteiro. Trata-se de uma busca binária. Acho que não há necessidade de postar tudo. Se houver necessidade, me falem que posto o restante

Answer (score -1):

Trate seu comando SQL como você fez no `print` do seu primeiro bloco de código.

Para qualquer versão de Python você pode passar o parâmetro na string do comando sql conforme abaixo

```
comando_sql2 = 'select data_ordenha from leite where id = %d' % chave
```

O `%d` recebe variáveis do tipo int. Use `%s` para variáveis do tipo string, ou seja

```
comando_sql2 = 'select data_ordenha from leite where id = %s' % str(chave)
```

Embora não me pareça ser o caso, lembre-se que em comandos SQL, campos do tipo varchar tem que estar entre apóstrofes e neste caso seria algo como:

```
comando_sql2 = "select data_ordenha from leite where vaca = '%s'" % "Mimosa"
```

**Nota** Perceba a substituição do apóstrofe por aspas, para que o campo pudesse ficar entre apóstrofe.

Caso a versão do Python seja 3.6 ou superior, você pode usar f-string

```
comando_sql2 = f"select data_ordenha from leite where id = {chave}"
```

**Nota** Aqui a string possui um `f` para indicar que é um f-string e a variável fica entre chaves.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor informar o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta